# React Fetch POST removes characters with header Content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am using *react* with `fetch` for sending an image to the server.
I have tried using  `Content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to pass my data to the server but it replaces special characters with spaces (i.e. `+` becomes a `space`).
I have switched the header to be `Content-type: multipart/form-data` but that throws the error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error).

I have added a boundary to the `Content-type` as `boundary=abcdefg`.
That did not change anything and I am not sure what my boundary would be.
Finding a clear answer with straight forward examples about boundaries have been impossible to get.
The data that I am sending is a large string.
If needed I can post that as well.

Here is a sample of the code that is causing the problem:

```
SaveTest4(data: string) {
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefg"
        },
        body: 'data=' + data
    }
    fetch('api/DataPoint/AddTest4', options);
}
```

Comment: have you tried something like: `body: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on part of your analysis, it sounds like you're trying to send base64-encoded data.  A content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will result in the server performing URL decoding, which will replace each instance of `+` in the content body with a space character.

When you used a content type of `multipart/form-data`, the server fails with status 500 because the data you provided wasn't a properly constructed MIME document.

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you're trying to post a base64-encoded file to a ASP.NET MVC WebAPI endpoint that's expecting a JSON document.  You might have a controller method that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("api/DataPoint/AddTest4")]
public void AddTest4([FromBody] string data) { ... }
```

If you send with a content type of `application/json`, this endpoint will expect a document that looks like this:

```
"{base64-encoded-data}"
```

Note that there are quotes around the data, because a quoted string is a proper JSON document.  You'd just use `JSON.stringify()` to create the quoted string in this case, which would escape any quotes within the string correctly.

If you send with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you'd need to send a document that looks like this:

```
data={base64-encoded-data}
```

But, as you note, you'd have to make sure you escape all of the special characters in the payload; you can do this using `window.encodeURIComponent()`, which would translate each "+" to "%2B", among other things.

If the files that you're uploading to this endpoint are large, it would be significantly better to use an instance of `FormData`.  This would allow the browser to stream the file to the server in chunks instead of reading it into memory and base64-encoding it in JavaScript.